# SSIS error when being called from .NET application

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have created a .NET web app in VS2013. It is populating a dropdown from a database, and then based on the selection, calling an SSIS package, importing some data, and creating output files in text and excel form. The package is in 2008 and 32 bit.

I am having no issues running this locally, but once deployed to a web server, I am getting the following error:

[image]

can anyone provide any insight? The Application pool has the option to run 32 bit applications enabled.

Comment: Copy and paste error text into your question , not the screenshot of it.

Comment: Did you "make sure that integration services are correctly installed on the computer that is running the application" Also did you "make sure that the 64 bit version is installed"

Comment: Yes, i made sure of both.

Comment: What is the version of sql server installed on your machine and on web server?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/491384d2-02f7-4178-a1c3-bcbd58e57fce/an-integration-services-class-cannot-be-found-make-sure-that-integration-services-is-correctly?forum=sqlintegrationservices

Comment: http://dougbert.com/blog/post/64-bit-considerations-for-sql-server-integration-services-final.aspx

Comment: My machine is 2008, 32 bit, the web server is 2008,r2 64 bit.

Answer (score 0):

**After searching for this error i found 4 issues that may cause this error:**

1. Package is deployed under 64-bit and integration services 64-bit is not installed on web server
2. Version mismatches between sql server on local machine and web server
3. You have changed property `ForcedExecutionValueType` for one component to a value different of `Int32`
4. Client SDK Tools not installed onn web server. Read more about SSIS recommendations in this [MSDN artcile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731.aspx)

**References**

- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/491384d2-02f7-4178-a1c3-bcbd58e57fce/an-integration-services-class-cannot-be-found-make-sure-that-integration-services-is-correctly?forum=sqlintegrationservices
- https://ask.sqlservercentral.com/questions/112696/make-sure-that-integration-services-is-correctly-i.html
- http://dougbert.com/blog/post/64-bit-considerations-for-sql-server-integration-services-final.aspx
- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143731.aspx
- https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/381445/sql-client-connectivity-sdk-and-client-tools-sdk-documentation